# Windows 10 WIFI list not showing, adapter can do connect only in manual

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking

In windows10-1909 pro x64 (Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265)  does not showing any networks. nor from system tray, nor from wifi setting panel. The console `netsh wlan show networks` reports available networks and it is possible to connect to any network given mannualy credential and SSID.  It seems not to be a driver problem as it was unistalled/purged from windows inf store /installed back. all the same.

any suggestions?

the applet icon doesnot work 
[image]
UPDATE: 1. I did network reset 
        2. i tryed out also all recipes with sfc,  restorehealth and online repair images

manual config is only work for wifi
    [image: the only way to setup wifi network for me]

UPDATE2: not only wifi applet does not work, but any right click action on any taskbar app doesn't work too! investigating the problem further i noticed that the **   defaultuser ** folder in windows10 user folder is not hidden and this name is like defaultuser01 and the second defaultuser02. 
Other note that on windows welcome/logon screen the wifi applet works normally. so i guess that problem is related to userprofile. the newly created  new user has the same problem.

Comment: Did you restart after reinstall?

Comment: Windows 10 won't even recognize that my 7265 *exists*... Ubuntu has no problem seeing it, so it's definitely not the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

The following might help:

- Run the Network troubleshooter
  Go to 
  *Settings > Network & Internet > Status > Network troubleshooter*
  and follow the steps in the troubleshooter.
- Temporarily turn off any antivirus or malware-prevention software
- Use network reset to reinstall network devices
  Go to *Settings  > Network & Internet  > Status > Network reset*,
  click on *Reset now*, answer Yes to confirm, then wait for the PC to restart
- Check in the Services applet if the Radio Management Service is started.

EDIT: Since none of the above did work,
network corruption is probably ruled out,
and my suspicion is now for Windows corruption.
The following measures you can take require precaution,
so take good backups first:

- Run `chkdsk` and if any errors are found then run `chkdsk /f`
- Run
  [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)
  and DISM
- And if all fails, then
  [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: no that doesn't work and that reset the list of known wifi. the problem is that i cant inquiry which service is broken. both applet wifi icon is not responding to any click, and in network adapter connect/disconnect context menu does nothing, no action

Comment: See my above addition.

Comment: plus to sfc check, did the repair image. seems that it defauluserprofile problem. noted in question update

Comment: @Yurij did you ever get this resolved? I'm having the same issue on a fresh Win10 install.

Comment: @3Dave: If your problem is different, then post a separate question. This one seems to be abandoned.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for the response. My problem appears to be the same.  And I have posted a new question with more detail. (https://superuser.com/questions/1594255/new-win10-install-wifi-bluetooth-and-other-ui-issues)

Comment: the advice could seems be strange but do you tried out install an additional language pack it could help