# New Win10 install. Wifi, bluetooth and other UI issues

Tags: windows-10, boot-camp, windows-networking

New Windows 10 x64 installation on a 16" MacBook Pro: i9, Radeon graphics, 16GB RAM, 768GB SSD. Running in Bootcamp (dual boot), not a VM.

When I click the wifi / network button on the notification area on the task bar, the little popup window listing available networks does not appear. If I go through the network settings applet in control panel, I also can't see available networks. However, if I log out and pick a network from the login screen, I can see the list and successfully connect to a network. I can also successfully list available networks from the command prompt.

Bluetooth is doing basically the same thing. If I go to the devices control panel applet and click the plus button to add a new bluetooth device, nothing happens. Enabling / disabling Bluetooth has no effect.

I've also tried deleting and reinstalling the wifi & bluetooth devices from device manager. I didn't think that would help, and it hasn't, but, hey, it was worth a shot.

Suggestions?

Comment: Have you updated to the latest Apple Support Tools - https://support.apple.com/HT204923 ? That's often a cause of flaky hardware recognition.

Comment: @Tetsujin Well, I just installed this a week or so ago. I'd expect Bootcamp Assistant to have pulled the correct tool version from Apple. I'll try and update. If it was flaky hardware recognition, why would it work from the login screen and via the command line?

Comment: That might be the very definition of flaky ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin LOL. You're not wrong. I'll give it a shot.